# How to use as.Date if there is NA, empty cells, and different formats within the same column?

Tags: r, na, as.date

Inside my data frame, a column consists of two kinds of date formats (`%Y-%m-%d` and `%d/%m/%Y`), empty cells, and NA. The following method is my attempt which did not produce the desired outcome. I tried to convert them as follow....

```
a <- as.Date(data$x, "%Y-%m-%d")
b <- as.Date(data$x, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then combine them together...

```
a[is.na(a)] <- b[!is.na(b)]
```

However, I get an error saying something about the different number of rows. I trust its due to the existence of empty cells and NA. Is there a way where I can put a + b together according to their row number/observation/ranking?

Thank you in advance for answering.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Check the anytime pckg

Comment: What do you want empty cells ('') and NA translated to? Also, please add reproducible data (use `dput()`)

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys. 

@smci I have no preference so long the NA and empty cells does not affect me manipulate the data. What would you have done if you faced the same problem? I tried changing it to "0000" but realized that they get changed back to NA when I apply as.Date to the data.

Comment: Well the old-and-trusted way of changing blank or NA dates such that they will be processed as a date and not result in variable-length output would be to change them to some sentinel value which is clearly meaningless, e.g. `9/9/9999`. But still please add say 10 example records of reproducible data.

Comment: Will do, please give me some time to understand how to share a reproducible data as I am still trying to understand @kgolyaev's code below. Already spent the morning trying to break it down and understand it but am finding it challenging. Im taking this seriously as I really want to understand it badly. Thanks for being patient.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is `ifelse`:

```
x = c("2012-01-01", "13/01/2012", "")
x1 = as.Date(x, format="%Y-%m-%d")
x2 = as.Date(x, format="%d/%m/%Y")
y = as.Date(
  ifelse(!is.na(x1), as.Date(x1), 
         ifelse(!is.na(x2), x2, x1)), 
  origin = as.Date("1970/01/01")
)
y
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-13" NA
```

For some reason I had to wrap the `ifelse` into `as.Date()`, otherwise the dates were printed as numbers, and not as actual dates. The `origin` argument is needed in this case.

**Edit**

Here is how the above code works. `ifelse(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)` is a vectorized function that expects three vectors of the same length as arguments. (The way R works, if one of these arguments is a single value, it will automatically be repeated proper number of times, the term for this is "broadcasting".) The execution of `ifelse()` is as follows:

a) For every element in `condition`, check whether it is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

b) If `condition` is `TRUE`, take the corresponding value from `value_if_true` vector.

c) Otherwise, if `condition` is `FALSE`, take the corresponding value from `value_if_false` vector

Now, you can nest `ifelse()` into each other, this way allowing for a three-way condition checking or even more if needed. Be warned that nesting more than a few `ifelse` calls can get really messy really fast.

With this knowledge, the above code should be straightforward to parse:

1) `x` creates an example vector of dates stored as strings with different formats.

2) `x1` parses the first date correctly, and fails to parse the second date.

3) `x2` parses the second date format correctly, but fails to parse the first date.

4) Then two nested `ifelse` calls combine correctly parsed dates into a single vector. First `ifelse` checks if the first date format was correctly parsed (`!is.na(x)` means "whenever value of `x` is not `NA`"), and returns non-missing values from `x1`. If `x1` is missing, it calls second `ifelse`, which returns non-missing values from `x2`, and then, if `x2` is also missing, it returns missing values into the final result.

5) For some reason, the nested `ifelse` calls return dates formatted as numbers rather than strings, so I wrap the result of 4) into `as.Date` to get nicely formatted dates back. In R, when you attempt to convert numbers to dates, you must provide the `origin` - dates are interpreted as number of days passed since some pre-defined origin date, which in R is Jan 1, 1970.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your method worked although I dont understand the reasoning behind it as im still relatively new to R and havent gotten a grasp of most concepts, but major thanks!! If you have the time, could you explain the usage of ifelse here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edited the answer a bit to explain things better.

Comment: Appreciate your time and effort to explain this to me. Youre a good person! Thanks a heap!